# How to edit a resource assembly in C# .net application

Tags: c#, .net, dll, localization, mono

Now, I am working on edit existing string/icon resource assembly which is code in C# in VS. I have search some method to edit the binary file directly, particularly, I use mono.cecil (http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/), almost all the localized resource files work fine. But only the English original resource file does not work. So I think I should give up this way, I hope to edit the file manually, either open source or original .net API is ok. Anyone have this kind experience to edit the resource file, please let me know:

BTW, the English project contains core logic code and references other dlls (OtherDLL.dll), this may cause exceptions when using mono.cecil, the code and exception is below.

```
AssemblyDefinition assemblyDefinition = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(resourceFileName);
// Some code
assemblyDefinition.Write(newFileName); // This will cause exception: "Failed to resolve assembly: 'OtherDLL, Version=10.1.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

The english dll is TestDll.dll under deployment directory, and other localized resource dlls are TestDll.resources.dll under localized directory, like /de/TestDll.resources.dll and /zh-CN/TestDll.resources.dll.

Now I need the method to achieve the target(edit and save resource part), so please help me to find a way to achieve the goal. Any comments will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is that you need to set the search directories for the assembly references in the metadata tables to be rewritten correctly:**

```
        var assemblyFile = @"c:\myassembly.dll";

        var resolver = new DefaultAssemblyResolver();
        
        // add directory of the source assembly for references
        resolver.AddSearchDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyFile));

        // add .NET runtime directories
        var runtimeDir = RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory();
        foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            resolver.AddSearchDirectory(dir);
        }

        var mod = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyFile, new ReaderParameters { AssemblyResolver = resolver }).MainModule;

        mod.Write(assemblyFile + ".patched");
```

**When you want to change resources with Mono.Cecil:**

```
        var strings = mod.Resources.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name == "English.resources");
        mod.Resources.Remove(strings);

        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using var rw = new ResourceWriter(ms);

        rw.AddResource("GreetingText", "Hello World");
        rw.Generate();
        
        ms.Position = 0;

        mod.Resources.Add(new EmbeddedResource("English.resources", ManifestResourceAttributes.Public, ms));

        mod.Write(assemblyFile + ".patched");
```

Regards